# How to test condition variable in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, testing

I have a pretty basic method that calls `wait()` on a condition variable (from `<condition_variable>` in C++.

```cpp
void WaitForEvent() {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
  while (!event_counter_) {
    cond_var_.wait(lock);
  } 
  return;
}
```

Now I want to unit test that method's interaction. So I want to call `WaitForEvent`, then call `PostEvent` which will notify the condition variable and check if the wait has stopped.

```cpp
void PostEvent() {
  // ...
  cond_var_.notify_all();
}
```

How'd I best do that in a unit test?

The only solution I've come up with so far is

1. start a thread that calls `WaitForEvent`
2. make the thread set a flag after the `WaitForEvent` call
3. call `PostEvent` in the main thread
4. wait for x seconds in the main thread
5. check if the flag has been set

However, I don't like the fact that I can't join the thread here. If I join,then my tests will block if `WaitForEvent` doesn't unblock as expected. Also, I don't like adding delays in unit tests.

Is there any better solution to my problem? Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT 1:** my first solution looks like this

```cpp
  SomeClass some_class{};
  bool has_unblocked = false;

  std::thread blocking_thread([&] {
    some_class.WaitForEvent();
    has_unblocked = true;
  });

  some_class.PostEvent();
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));

  REQUIRE(has_unblocked == true);

  blocking_thread.join();
```

Comment: In your solution `sleep_for` should be just after the `blocking_thread`, otherwise it's possible that you call `notify_all` before `wait`.

Comment: Re, "4. wait for x seconds in the main thread." Why not `join()` the thread created in step 1 instead of delaying the test for some arbitrary time interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do similar things in a few of my unit tests that involve threads and mashalling events/messages between threads.  What you propose is not a bad strategy.

One thing that stands out about your question it that it seems like your unit test is simply testing the behavior of `std::condition_variable` and not the behavior of your code that is implemented with a cond_var. I always tell my team to be wary of writing tests that are only testing the platform and c++ runtime - because we know that works. I suspect there's more to your test than the Wait and Post code, but it's just something I want to point out. Because once you realize that, you can consider just having the Wait and Post code be overridden in a unit test.

> If I join,then my tests will block if WaitForEvent doesn't unblock as expected.

But in the success case, it will not matter because your code works and the test completes quickly. If it does block forever, your unit tests have uncovered a real bug.  That's a good thing right? (Other than your team members complaining that the unit tests are hanging again.)

But if you want to avoid the possibility of a deadlock in UT code, you could have a variation of your wait that uses `wait_for` instead `wait`.  Where maybe the product code doesn't rely on the timeout, but the UT does....

```
class SomeClass
{
    bool _running_as_unittest;
    void WaitForEvent() {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
      while (!event_counter_) {
        if (_running_as_unittest) {
            cond_var.wait(lock, FiveSeconds); // give the test a chance to escape
            if (!event_counter) {
                _errorCondition = true;
            }
        }
        else {
           cond_var.wait(lock); // wait forever
        } 
      } 
      return;
    }
…
}
```

Then your test code:

```
  SomeClass some_class{};
  bool has_unblocked = false;
  some_class._running_as_unittest = true;
  some_class._errorCondition = false;

  std::thread blocking_thread([&] {
    some_class.WaitForEvent();
    has_unblocked = true;
  });

  some_class.PostEvent();
  for (int x = 0; (x < 500) && !has_unblocked; x++) {
       std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
  }

  REQUIRE(has_unblocked == true);
  REQUIRE(someclass._errorCondition == false);

  // todo - if has_unblocked is false, you could consider invoking `blocking_thread.native_handle` and then invoking `pthread_kill` or `TerminateThread` as appropriate. instead of invoking `join`.

  blocking_thread.join();
```

Comment: Thank you very much - that answered all my questions :) Also, my test actually tests more behavior - I just wanted to show the relevant parts here to not confuse any of the readers :D

Comment: I don't like the idea of writing additional interfaces for `SomeClass` (like `running_as_unittest`) only to simplify testing. This can lead to circular dependencies and is more bug-prone (because in the end it's not exactly the same code as run in production). In my organization this technique will be rejected.

Comment: @Ptaq666 - I was weary to suggest adding behaviors to the product code class for the purposes of unit testing too.  The better workaround would be to isolate the conditional variable usage into virtual functions.  Then in the Unit Test, just override those methods with another class deriving from "SomeClass".  Or use g-mock to change behavior.  All kinds of possibilities. The point of my answer was to just encourage the OP he was on the right path with his solution and to not get carried away with the deadlock issue.

Answer (score 1):

In this situations I usually use `std::async` to return an `std::future` and I also specify the operation timeout to avoid tests that got stuck in CI.

```
#include <future>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>

class MySystem {
public:
    MySystem() = default;
    std::future<bool> WaitForEvent(std::chrono::milliseconds timeout) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(cv_m_);
        return std::async(std::launch::async,
            // for this lambda you need C++14
            [this, timeout, lock{std::move(l)}] () mutable {
            if (cv_.wait_for(lock, timeout) == std::cv_status::timeout) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
    void PostEvent() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(cv_m_);
        cv_.notify_all();
    }

private:
    std::condition_variable cv_;
    std::mutex cv_m_;
};

TEST(xxx, yyy) {
    MySystem sut;
    auto result = sut.waitForEvent(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    ASSERT_FALSE(result.get());
    result = sut.waitForEvent(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    sut.PostEvent();
    ASSERT_TRUE(result.get());
}
```

`std::future` saves me the effort of creating and joining threads manually and allows me to check the result of the operation in a nice way (e.g. `false` in case of timeout). Locking `std::mutex` before invoking `std::async` guarantees that your `condition_variable` will start waiting before you execute `notify_all`.